# New menu entry in GRUB2, "file not found" and "you need to load the kernel first" errors

Tags: debian, boot, dual-boot, lvm, grub2

I wanted to add new menu entry to my GRUB2 list. This is how I tried to do this and necessary info:

**Erros** after choosing "Debian Wheezy" menu entry from GRUB2 list:

```
error:file not found
error:you need to load the kernel first
```

**/etc/grub.d/12_debian**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cat << EOF
menuentry "Debian Wheezy" {
set root=(hd0,5)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
}
EOF
```

**ls /boot**

```
config-3.2.0-3-amd64  initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64  vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64
grub                  System.map-3.2.0-3-amd64
```

**Partitioning**

```
sda1 - ntfs - Windows boot
sda2 - ntfs - Windows C:
sda3 - ntfs - Windows D:
sda4 - extended
-sda5 - ext4 - /boot
-sda6 - lvm - Debian testing
And inside sda6 there's LVM group calld G1 divided into volumes:
home, root, tmp, usr, var, swap
```

**Sources** that I used during my unsuccessful of setting everything up.

[GRUB2 Naming convention](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Naming-convention)

[GRUB 2 bootloader - Full tutorial on Dedoimedo.com](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId584691)

What's wrong?

**EDIT #1**

**fdisk -l**

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    83473739    41633446    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        83473799   935802314   426164258    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       935802315   976771071    20484378+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       935802880   936779775      488448   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       936781824   976771071    19994624   8e  Linux LVM
```

**EDIT #2**

**Grub console**

```
linux /[TAB]
Possible files are:
lost+found/ bin/ share/ sbin/ lib/ include/ src/ games/ local/

set root=(hd0,msdos5)
linux/[TAB]
Possible files are:
lost+found/ config-3.2.0-3-amd64 vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64 grub/ 
System.map-3.2.0-3-amd64 initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
```

**Grub console, boot test**

```
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
linux /vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64 root=/dev/G1/root
initrd /initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
boot

#Many, many, many lines of text. After few seconds they stop. The most
#interesting i think are:

ALERT! /dev/G1/root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

**/etc/grub.d/12_debian another try**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cat << EOF
menuentry "Debian Wheezy" {
insmod ext4
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
echo 'loading...'
linux /vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64
echo 'starting kernel...'
initrd /initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
}
EOF
```

**Result:**

```
error:file not found
loading...
starting kernel...
```

**EDIT #3**

**part of /boot/grub/grub.cfg**

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-3-amd64' --class debian --    class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod gzio
    insmod lvm
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(G1-root)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 94215fad-dcbe-4339-92be-f562b1b37133
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-3-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/G1-root ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
```

**/etc/grub.d/12_debian next try**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cat << EOF
menuentry "Debian Wheezy" {
insmod ext4
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
echo 'loading...'
linux /vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/G1-root
echo 'starting kernel...'
initrd /initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
}
```

**Result**

```
error:file not found
loading...
starting kernel...
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a dedicated /boot partition ( you probably don't need one ), that partition has no directory named /boot, hence why the files are not found.  Remove the /boot from the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
menuentry "Debian Wheezy" {
insmod ext4
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
echo 'loading ..'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64
echo 'starting kernel ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
}
```

Comment: Still, the same problem:
error: file not found.
loading...
error:file not found.
starting kernel...
error:you need to load the kernel first

Where I could make a mistake? Maybe there's something I could check that'll help with diagnosis? I've posted "fdisk -l" in my question.

Comment: I will suggest you to first troubleshoot it at grubs command prompt. Probably grub is unable to locate the file.You can put command in line by line order, and use tab key to see if grub can locate the file.Example `linux [press TAB]/boot/[press TAB]` if your file is listed then its some other problem otherwise use a right value in `set root`

Comment: I think that there's some progress... I added some new info in my first post!

Comment: @r4czek:- Can you paste your grub.cfg somewhere where I can read.I'll recommend to copy paste the contents from some other menu after `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64`. like `root=UUID=...` OR `root=/dev/disk/by-id/...`

Comment: @perlibrain
That was my first guess and I've tried it without success... I posted everything you asked for and another try with my menuentry.
PS. Thank you for your endurance and help!

Comment: Where did you get this stuff from? Installing a kernel should create the correct entries automatically...

Comment: @vonbrand well, 9y into future and no, sometimes correct entries aren't created automatically, neither by grub2-mkconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...old thread but it seems like it was never resulted in working answer.  I recently had a similar issue which is now fixed.  For others with similar issues I recommend changing

```
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
```

to the following

```
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root '5bbd33b6-3333-3a33-3333-8045d333bb63'
```

where 1234-567A is the UUID for the desired partition obtained from

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda5
```

The result of which will look something like the following.

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="5bbd33b6-3333-3a33-3333-8045d333bb63" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="0c33e3ab-d3dc-3af3-333d-a33eee3c333c"
```